# JSR-303 activation in jsonschema2pojo

Tags: json, bean-validation, jsonschema2pojo

There is a place in **jsonschema2pojo** documentation describing possibility to enable [JSR-303 annotations generation](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Reference#minimummaximum-minitemsmaxitems-minlengthmaxlength-required-pattern). If I understand correctly it can be done via Maven plugin configuration. Could someone show how to accomplish it, which tag in plugin configuration should be used? Thanks to all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`includeJsr303Annotations`](http://joelittlejohn.github.io/jsonschema2pojo/site/0.4.2/generate-mojo.html#includeJsr303Annotations) parameter. See the plugin [documentation](http://joelittlejohn.github.io/jsonschema2pojo/site/0.4.2/generate-mojo.html#includeJsr303Annotations):

> ### includeJsr303Annotations
>
> Whether to include [JSR-303 annotations](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) (for schema rules like `minimum`, `maximum`, etc) in generated Java types. Schema rules and the annotation they produce:
>
> - `maximum` = [`@DecimalMax`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMax.html)
> - `minimum` = [`@DecimalMin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html)
> - `minItems`, `maxItems` = [`@Size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html)
> - `minLength`, `maxLength` = [`@Size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html)
> - `pattern` = [`@Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html)
> - `required` = [`@NotNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html)
>
> Any Java fields which are an object or array of objects will be annotated with [`@Valid`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html) to support validation of an entire document tree.
>
> - **Type:** `boolean`
> - **Since:** 0.3.2
> - **Required:** No
> - **Expression:** `${jsonschema2pojo.includeJsr303Annotations}`
> - **Default:** `false`

It can be used as following:

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.27</version>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
            <targetPackage>com.example.types</targetPackage>
            <includeJsr303Annotations>true</includeJsr303Annotations>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin Oops... I've just seen your answer.

Comment: can we also provide a message for those annotations?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the [place](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/blob/master/jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/jsonschema2pojo/maven/Jsonschema2PojoMojo.java) there Maven plugin configuration tags are described, "includeJsr303Annotations" should be used for my case.